# Slice option in Unity greyed out

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use the automatic slicer but the Slice button is greyed out for me as seen here :

[image]

I am also getting the error :

```
(!IsPowerOfTwo(width) || !IsPowerOfTwo(height)) 
         && !IsNPOTTextureAllowed(mipCount > 1)
```

How can I work around this?

Comment: You need to make sure your SpriteMode is set to Multiple not Single

Comment: @Savlon where do I do that?

Answer (score 8):

1. **Select your sprites in project**
2. Select the SpriteMode to be **Multiple**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Keep as `Single`, but turn off `Generate Mip Maps`

Answer (score 0):

For me, my Inspector was in Debug mode. Changing to Normal mode activated the Slice option.